# Adding methods to AuthenticatedWebSession in Wicket 7 by extension

Tags: java, wicket

I'm using Wicket 7 and extending **AuthenticatedWebSession** as a class called **BasicAuthenticatedSession**. While I'm doing this, I'd like to add a method that returns some additional information about the authenticated user.

In **BasicAuthenticatedSession#authenticate**, I get a **Sysuser** object which is a wrapper for a user in the database. I use some of the information in this object for the authentication, but want to have access to all of the info (firstname, lastname, etc.) throughout the session.

I was expecting to be able to create a new method call **getUser** which would return this database object to the caller.

However, this method, even though declared public, isn't visible when attempting to call it. I'm not sure if this is something to do with Wicket, or just a general misunderstanding on my part how inheritance works. ;)

**BasicAuthenticatedWebSession.java**

```
public class BasicAuthenticatedWebSession extends AuthenticatedWebSession {

    public BasicAuthenticatedWebSession(Request request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        Sysuser[] sysusers;

        try {
            SysuserCriteria userCriteria = new SysuserCriteria();

            userCriteria.username.eq(username);
            sysusers = Sysuser.listSysuserByCriteria(userCriteria);
        } catch (PersistentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return false;
        }

        if (sysusers.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        this.username = username;
        this.userid   = sysusers[0].getId();

        return password.compareTo(sysusers[0].getPasswd()) == 0;
    }

    public Roles getRoles() {
        Roles     roles = new Roles();
        Sysuser[] sysusers;

        if (isSignedIn()) {
            roles.add("SIGNED_IN");
        }

        try {
            SysuserCriteria sysuserCriteria = new SysuserCriteria();

            sysuserCriteria.username.eq(username);
            sysusers = Sysuser.listSysuserByCriteria(sysuserCriteria);

            for (Object sysuser : sysusers) {
                SysroleSetCollection sysroles = ((Sysuser) sysuser).sysrole;

                for (Sysrole sysrole : sysroles.toArray()) {
                    roles.add(sysrole.getRolename().toUpperCase());
                }
            }
        } catch (PersistentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return roles;
    }

    public Sysuser getSysuser() {
        return sysuser;
    }
}
```

**Test.java** This class fails to compile as the *getSysuser* method in **BasicAuthenticatedSession** is not found.

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {
    }

    public void foo {
        if(BasicAuthenticatedSession.get().isSignedIn()) {
            Sysuser sysUser = BasicAuthenticatedSession.get().getSysuser();
            System.out.println(sysuser.getFirstname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: I'v pasted this code, seems one bracket } missing ?

Comment: What returns 'BasicAuthenticatedSession.get()' ?  Your class or base AuthenticatedWebSession ? This is typical change in every Wicket project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket project require specific "override" of static methods, I guess that You return original wicket API session. Edited copy from my project (session is Your classname)

```
public class BasicAuthenticatedWebSession extends AuthenticatedWebSession {

public static BasicAuthenticatedWebSession get() {
        return (BasicAuthenticatedWebSession ) Session.get();
    }

...
}
```

and in XxxxxApplication class

```
public class MyProject extends AuthenticatedWebApplication
{
    ...

@Override
    public Session newSession(Request request, Response response) {
        return new BasicAuthenticatedWebSession (request);
    }
}
```